# How to get notified when Spark streaming starts to process a file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I make use of Spark to read streaming data from a folder and I want to get notified when it picks up my file and starts to process it so that I can print a log to indicate that the application is reading the file and this may take some time.

I've implemented a user defined function (udf) to achieve this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{input_file_name, udf}
spark.readStream
    .option("pathGlobFilter",fileFilter)
    .option("enforceSchema", false)
    .option("header", includeHeader)
    .option("inferSchema", inferSchema)
    .options(otherOptions)
    .schema(csvSchema.orNull)
    .csv(finalPath)
    .withColumn("filename",<UDF_FUNCTION>)(input_file_name))
```

**UDF_FUNCTION** is a simple udf function which just logs a message for the first row read by Spark for the file.

Unfortunately, this approach adds a new column and I'd like to learn whether there is a better way to accomplish this functionality.

I'm using Spark 3.4.1 and Scala 2.13.10.